How do I remove the "Not secure" warning in Chrome?
I'm bringing up a page from a media server on my home network and Chrome has a persistent "Not secure" warning at the top of the page. The warning is not necessary and I want to remove this to watch things in full screen.
Changing the "Safe browsing" and "Secure connections" settings had no effect. There does not seem to be any relevant features in chrome://flags/.

It shows even when you make it full screen? Typically, the Not Secure warning is only there in the side of the address bar, which is hidden when going full screen. Can you edit your question and add a screenshot?

I'm having trouble imagining this. a picture would help.

I don't think you can do this just within Chrome settings.
Assuming your media server is not externally reachable - doing what you ask is not trivial.  What you need to do is

Ensure that your media server uses a domain name rather then an IP address if you have not done so already.  (Doesn't really matter what the domain name is - it can, for example be mediaserver.local).  You will need to modify your router, DNS or hosts files to affect resolution of this domain to its IP address.

You will likely need to create your own CA  (Certificate Authority).   This is non-trivial, but there are multiple systems to help with this. Google "create my own CA".   There are some alternatives to this, but they cost money, are very inconvenient and will become moreso - see my comments below.

You need to import your CA's public key into your Chrome browser keystore.

You will need to generate a public/private keypair and sign that with your CA - and then configure your media server to use this key pair.


As an alternative to steps 2 and 3 you could register a domain, point the domain to the IP address of your media server (doesn't matter that its an internal IP address), purchase a cert from a known CA and install this as per 4 above.  This is not a great solution though because these certs are only valid for 1 year and cost money - and in the future they will be valid only for 3 months.
If your setup is more sophisticated there are other options - for example you may be able to use Letsencrypt to generate the cert for you if you can hook it into your DNS or the media server can be world accessible - however there are other issues/concerns here, and I posit you would not be asking this question if you had the requisite knowledge to do this.
